# Android app crashing on startup

Tags: java, android

I have just started android app development..and while opening the following app it says `"Unfortunately your app has crashed"`. Can anyone point out the error in this code.

**fragmentmain.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffbb"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:text="Info of Departments and Student Bodies"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //adding items to list view
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String values[] = new String[]{"Departments" , "Student_bodies"};
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0 ; i < values.length; ++i){
        list.add(values[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> ap = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    listview.setAdapter(ap);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            if (((TextView)arg1).getText().toString() == "Departments"){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Departments.class));
            }
            if (((TextView)arg1).getText().toString() == "Student_bodies"){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Student_bodies.class));
            } 
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

it is just simple implementation of list view and implementing `onClick()` on its elements to go to different `Activity`.thankful if  anyone points out mistakes.

Comment: Can you post your logcat please?

Comment: Would need your LogCat.

Comment: you should override onViewCreate inside PlaceholderFragment, and move all the listview related logic inside this method. At least your application will not crash at startup.

Comment: I don't know why it crashing, but you can't compare strings using ==
`((TextView)arg1).getText().toString() == "Departments"` use `.equals()` method insted

Comment: @user3696330 you can extend Activity and remove all extra code. place the listview in your activity_main.xml if fragment concept is not required in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout file named `FragmentMain` but You using `activity_main` as parameter of `setContentView()` method. Try to change to `setContentView(R.layout.FragmentMain);`

Comment: thanks for suggestion ..my app is working after this change

Answer (score 0):

Please remove code from onCreate() and added in onCreateView(), as you are using fragment.
And your listview is also define in fragment_main.xml ,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 final ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String values[] = new String[]{"Departments" , "Student_bodies"};
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0 ; i < values.length; ++i){
        list.add(values[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> ap = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    listview.setAdapter(ap);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            if (((TextView)arg1).getText().toString() == "Departments"){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Departments.class));
            }
            if (((TextView)arg1).getText().toString() == "Student_bodies"){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Student_bodies.class));
            } 
        }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: wrong ... he IS using an `Activity`. he has extended from `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Sir, please check his xml and where its actually used.

Comment: oops right ... sorry!